# Is any other DLL except FFmpeg for to convert any video format in to mp4 formate using C#

Tags: c#

The reason for avoiding FFmpeg dll because of size, the size of the dll is around 13 MB so please any one suggest me for this problem. I want dll in less size or code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: for video processing the size is not large?

Comment: yes, want to convert any video format to mp4 ..

Comment: Thank you lei yang for the reply .. have any solution for this ?

Comment: i think you'd better google **algorithm video to mp4**, but if you want to convert from **any** type, then the library cannot be small.

Comment: Give me some dll with similar to FFmpeg.

Comment: try [http://vlc.net/](http://vlc.net/)